# iOS 7 - UITextView size font to fit all text into view (no scroll)

Tags: ios7, resize, uitextview, sizewithfont

I am trying to find a non-deprecated method to size the font of a textview down so that all text fits in the textview without requiring scrolling.

The method 'sizeWithFont' is deprecated and I want to ensure best practices, and XCode says to use 'boundingRectWithSize' but not sure how to use this to size a font down so that all text fits.

Any suggestions?
And NO I can not use a UILabel instead. I need to have the text vertically aligned at the top and UILabel does not do this.

**This worked Pre-iOS 7:**

```
CGFloat fontSize;
CGFloat minSize;
if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPad"] || [deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPad Simulator"]){
    fontSize = 40;
    minSize = 15;
}
else{
    fontSize = 18;
    minSize = 8;
}
while (fontSize > minSize)
{
    CGSize size = [quote sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Interstate" size:fontSize] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(newView.frame.size.width, 10000)];

    if (size.height <= newView.frame.size.height) break;

    fontSize -= 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Solution 1

Your problem can be solved by simply replacing `sizeWithFont: constrainedToSize:` with :

```
boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(newView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)
                options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
             attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Interstate" size:fontSize]}
                context:nil];
```

#### Solution 2

The `sizeThatFits` method can be used to address this problem like this:

```
while (fontSize > minSize &&  [newView sizeThatFits:(CGSizeMake(newView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX))].height >= newView.frame.size.height ) {
    fontSize -= 1.0;
    newView.font = [tv.font fontWithSize:fontSize];
}
```

I hope one of these solutions solve your problem. Cheers!

Comment: Awesome! Solution 1 didn't work for me, it actually made the font extremely large. But solution 2 did the trick! Thanks!!

Comment: Those, who cant got what is newView here - check `bicycle` answer below

Comment: I love you, nice Solution :)

Comment: This somewhat works. Doesn't work well for typing individual characters for me...

Answer (score 4):

I had to do the same but then with programmatically added AutoLayout constraints (`NSLayoutConstraint`). Because of the constraints the `contentSize` wasn't correct for the most time causing the `UITextView` to scroll :/ To still get the correct font size I ended up just creating a new `UITextView` for the sake of doing some good ol' trial and error testing and getting it through there.

Pretty simple but like with everything you just gotta come up with it :)

```
NSInteger fontSize = 200;

UITextView *testTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
testTextView.text = self.myRealTextView.text;
testTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AldotheApache" size:fontSize];
while ([testTextView sizeThatFits:(CGSizeMake(self.myRealTextView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX))].height >= self.myRealTextView.frame.size.height ) {
    fontSize -= 0.5;
    testTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AldotheApache" size:fontSize];
}

NSLog(@"Correct font size is: %ld",(long)fontSize);

self.myRealTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AldotheApache" size:fontSize];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try UITextView's `sizeThatFits`. You can probably use it the following way:

```
//Set  text content of UITextView
//...

while (fontSize > minSize) {

   // Set font size of UITextView

   CGSize size = [textView sizeThatFits:(CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)];

   if (size.height <= newView.frame.size.height) break;

   fontSize -= 1.0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

UITextView is subclass of UIScrollView -> so you can check the contentSize of the scrollable area after you set your text or font into textView.

```
textView.text = quote;
do
{
    textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Interstate" size:fontSize];
    [textView layoutIfNeeded];
    if (textView.contentSize.height <= newView.frame.size.height) {
        break;
    }
    fontSize -= 1.0;
} while (fontSize >= minSize);
```

That should work... Probably it would work even without [textView layoutIfNeeded].

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5+

```
    var fontSize = Font.Size.section.rawValue
    let minSize = Font.Size.large.rawValue

    while fontSize > minSize {
        let textViewSize = CGSize(width: textView.frame.size.width, height: textView.frame.size.height)
        let size = textView.sizeThatFits(textViewSize)

        if size.height <= textViewSize.height {
            break
        }

        fontSize -= 1.0
    }

    textView.font = Font.primary.of(size: fontSize)
```